# Please help me install

Tags: uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I have an ASUS ux32a
It pre loaded with Windows 8. I seems to be an UEFI.

I have always used Ubuntu on my old pc but now I have a laptop.

I am scared to lose Windows 8 totally.
My 500 GB drive is factory partitioned. How do I re-partition. What is the best method of installing it?
I am very confused about this. My old pc was Ubuntu only which I managed.

Do I need to make system image of Windows or is it not necessary?

Is there any one I can talk to to  me...I am desparate.

Also is Lubuntu a better option for a basic user?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it is always a good idea to make a backup/image before messing with the hard drive in a potentially dangerous (data wise) way.
2. There are a lot of people that can help you. I would start with disabling UEFI in the BIOS, then booting off the live disk.
3. Lubuntu is a fast and lightweight operating system developed by a community of Free and Open Source enthusiasts. (lubuntu.net) if this sound interesting to you, then try it. The cool thing about Ubuntu though is you can install all the Desktop Environments and use the one you want at any given time, without having to re-install your OS.