# Being new to Ubuntu/Linux, how does one match a brand new laptop to the appropriate version of Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a brand new Lenovo ideapad U530, pre-installed windows 8.1 64bit 1TB with an ssd.

With so many different variations of Linux I'm confused to which one will work the best 
for my laptop specs.

I've done some research and read many reviews. Some issues relating to overheating, issues in BIOS vs UEFI modes, wireless connection problems etc.

I would be extremely thankful if someone could recommend wither I should choose Ubuntu
12.04 LTS, LinuxMint, Luna, Linuxlite, Fedora, Kubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please help me install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250277/please-help-me-install)

Comment: @Alvar did you actually read that and this question?

Comment: yeah wrong copy intended to copy the dupe of that question...

Comment: Well, I've bought close-outs on sale at the local office supply store, and I bring in a bootable USB with the latest LTS version with me. If everything seems to work (wifi included), I feel pretty safe. A quick Google search of the model and Ubuntu should bring up any major incompatibilities. It's worked the last three notebooks.

Comment: Related: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I got your back so prepare to get.... an answer:

The reason why you should chose Ubuntu ( I say 12.04)  it's because Ubuntu is backed up by Canonical, you see in order for any Linux distro out there to get updates to be: secured, increase performance.... there must be people out there to do that, Canonical is not just some 21 year old computer geek who is still learning Canonical it's a bussines they know what they are doing so being backed up by Canoical Ubuntu it's more reliable, it's more stable and secured. Other distros are developed by either a group either even one person but not much  an Enterprise.

The reason why you should chose 12.04 is because it's LTS (Long Term Support) Canonical will offer updates for this distro for a long time this makes the developers able to make good software for Ubuntu since they have the ensuring from Canonical that the distro is going to be "alive" until 2017.
   There are a lot of great Linux  projects out there that is just great but really if you look on the market there are really only 3 of them RedHat (for like BIG data centers, big cloud infrastructure)
Ubuntu (more geard toward end user (home user) but also on servers and cloud) and Suse with Suse Linux Enterpise the same for all .

For example  really popular software it's available for Ubuntu such as : Skype, Steam, Teamviwer, GoogleChrome and a lot more on the Ubuntu Software Center, Other distros such as Fedora don't come with Steam,Skype you can get them wroking but... not even legal for example Ubuntu has access to legal MP3 encoding and other movie / music formats, again because Ubuntu look towards end-users such us you and me.

Comment: Sorry, you seem to be unaware of how the wider Linux world works. RedHat is not a "21 year old geek", and neither is Novell (both of whom are _far_ larger than Canonical). Various distros had been around (and getting regular updates) for decades before Ubuntu was even created. You are completely ignoring Debian which has a huge user base as well as Mint which is both more popular than Ubuntu and more geared towards the end user (e.g. much simpler mp3 support ). Bottom line, Ubuntu is no more reliable or secured than any of the top distros a "corporation" is not needed to make a distro safe.

Comment: Is it more beneficial to use a usb or a disk? I'm going to get rid of the bloatware on the new laptop, but how do I add that new free space to my c drive?

Comment: I think you should  use a USB

Comment: to add the free space  right click my computer -> manage -> go to the c drive and there is a option to increase volume

Answer (score 3):

This is really mostly a matter of taste, and I would advise you to try out and judge for yourself. There simply isn't a unique answer here.

I recommend taking a look at [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major) which makes a good job in listing many popular distributions and their differences.

Ubuntu is certainly a good distribution to start with, easily usable by newbies yet as powerful as any Linux for advanced users. But so are many other distributions.

If it's going to be Ubuntu, you should choose between Ubuntu 12.04 (long time support) or Ubuntu 13.10 (the latest release). An LTS version typically has older software without the newest cutting-edge features, but provides a stable experience and you won't have to update for a long time. A non-LTS version such as 13.10 will give you newer software, yet it is only supported for 9 months, so you will have to do an upgrade sometime mid-2014 at the latest.

Comment: "Most popular distributions" in terms of people visiting Distrowatch and clicking on certain items? AFAIK, the Distrowatch people themselves don't attach "real life" significance to the numbers.

Comment: Your answer along with @Daniel response seems logical based on the theory that Ubuntu is user friendly to newbies. The 12.04 LTS version just makes it even more suitable because of the support.

Comment: In addition to your answer, the recommendation to look at DistroWatch was a great resource.

Comment: @DKBose Of course, but it gives you an idea. I edited the post, though.

Comment: @Grant You may also want to consider waiting for Ubuntu 14.04 (or upgrading from 12.04 ro 14.04). Ubuntu 14.04 will also be LTS, with newer software than 12.04.